# MBProgressHud.h file not found

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ionic-framework

I have download **MBProgressHUD.m and MBProgressHUD.h** file from github  and

Placed under a folder **Classes->MBprogressHub->then both files**

Now i have include this file under Share Extension

## import "MBProgressHUD.h".

When i an trying to build an app. it is giving me an error. MBProgressHUD.h not found.

any idea how to resolve this.

I am using ionic framwork and new to ios and mac.

Error ScreenShot

[image]

Thanks

Comment: can you show error message which you got?

Comment: @PravinTate: i have added the screen shot

Comment: Problem is solved or till there? Please follow my ans as well as ashish's ans

Comment: `#import <MBProgressHUD/MBProgressHUD.h>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do as suggested by Pravin Tate.

If problem not solved, In addition :

Set the target membership for the `MBProgressHUD` with the `BiblioHiveShare`

[image]

You will found target membership in `MBProgressHUD` files

Remove the files from your project.

When you add it back then you will find this window.

[image]

Select the targets

If you added new target manually then you can change target from File inspector at right panel

[image]

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Could you please tell me where i need to add target membership. i am not able to find this ..

Comment: @HituBansal updated the answer. Hope it will help you

Answer (score 2):

Do following

- Go to finder/Library/Developer/Xcode
- delete **DerivedData** that folder
- Clean your project
- build it again

If there is still error, restart Xcode.

This approach worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

use cocoapods for handling 3rd party in your application.
see this site for more information :- https://cocoapods.org

Comment: Although this might be a solution to his problem, it does not answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 Go to you your project folder

Step 2 Open the pod file (if your using mac use this command **vi Podfile**)

Step 3 after you have open the PodFile add these line

**pod 'MBProgressHUD', '~> 1.0.0'**

Step 4 save the changes made to the file

Step 5 then in terminal **pod install**

Step 6 clean your xcode project and run

Answer (score 0):

I had this when opening the project file (`.xcodeproj`) instead of the workspace (`.xcworkspace`) file in Xcode.  The one has a refernce to the pods project, the other doesn't, so won't see the dependencies needed to make the build.